# Social sharing on Android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, social-networking, google-plus

So sharing on social channels is a hot topic these days. 
I have done some research on how to share to Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and G+.

Lets start with an example.. I want to share text, and an image to 4 social channels (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and G+), but without the user adding more text.

My findings so far:

1. You can use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` but there are a lot of limitations like:

   - You need to make your own chooser if you want to filter the social channels
   - Sending text and image is not possible without the user adding more text
2. Using default social channel APIs, but:

   - Can be overhead, you only want to share.
   - Are not always stable.
3. There are some open source libraries you can use, but they are not as complete as you may think
4. Use paid services (do I need to say more...)

So in conclusion, I need help. What is the way to go?.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything for the `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. Specifically because the apps listed  are meant to handle this intent.

This should be perfectly fine because you'd rather have the user's choose what they'd like to share it on then constrain them to one. I'd say if you're looking to share then stick with the standard on android and use `ACTION_SEND`.

You can't expect the user to have Application A when they may prefer using Application B. Don't think in terms of constraint.

Also as your comment about the limitation of `ACTION_SEND`.. I'd recommend re-reading the documentation because I don't see that limitation anywhere:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

Comment: Try to share a picture and text on facebook without showing you an Facebook dialog, you can't

Comment: Of course you can't because they want you to go to their app and confirm the posting. This is by design and is not a problem/bug.

Comment: You can share without intervention, but you are bound to the Facebook API, so they have a different design.

Comment: Yes, because that is using the Facebook API and it not constrained to an app, so they are designed differently and rightfully so due to the contextual usage.

Comment: So I need custom implementations for all social channels. I did stumble upon https://github.com/sdossick/SocialLib wich looks promising

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SocialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)which supports 10 social providers and it provides you functionality's like share text , upload image , get albums , feeds etc.